# Xcode derived data location

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode keeps writing derived data to the project folder even though its set to default in the xcode project settings, its there any way to force this other than the project settings?

Comment: For Xcode 6 you can get help [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039932/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode6

Answer (score 73, accepted):

By default Xcode stores the derived data for all projects in a single shared folder under your home directory at the following location:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Update:

From Xcode 6, you can access or change derived data location from **Preferences -> Locations Tab**

[image]

Comment: if you want access the value from command line this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808494/669692