# Determine Xcode derived data location from command line

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to determine from the command line what the location of your derived data folder is after building with xcodebuild?

For example, after running xcodebuild:

```
xcodebuild -project projectname -target targetname
```

I want to be able to find out which folder the app is in. I would like to do this without changing the output path with CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR or within the project settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
xcodebuild -project myapp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings
```

prints all build settings and values, in particular the folder where the app is build:

> BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR =
>   /path/to/myapp/DerivedData/myapp/Build/Products/Release

Comment: There was a similar question shortly after yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826375/is-it-possible-to-export-user-defined-xcode-build-settings-to-environment-variab/13827487#13827487, perhaps that is also of interest.

Comment: I got what I wanted with some grepping like this: `xcodebuild -project projectname -target targetname -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR" | grep -oEi "\/.*"`

Comment: unfortunately the path differs in the random postfix :/. I have no idea why… Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean "Release" at the end, add `-configuration Debug` or the like to control that.