# Is it possible to export user defined XCode build settings to environment variables

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have made a few build settings for various configurations, e.g.

[image: Build settings] e.g.

I can access them in various files (e.g. the info.plist) like so:

```
${MYTESTSETTING}
```

However is it possible to get the value in the command line enviroment? e.g. after a xcodebuild from Jenkins

I have tried

```
echo ${MYTESTSETTING}
```

And

```
echo $MYTESTSETTING
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings
```

shows all build settings, including the user-defined settings. Example:

```
$ xcodebuild -configuration Debug -showBuildSettings | grep MYTESTSETTING
    MYTESTSETTING = DebugValue
$ xcodebuild -configuration Release -showBuildSettings | grep MYTESTSETTING
    MYTESTSETTING = ReleaseValue
```

To get these variables into the environment of your current shell, you have to parse this output. This can for example be done with a Perl script (or many other scripting languages).

Create a Perl script "exportsettings.pl" with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FH, "xcodebuild -configuration Release -showBuildSettings|");
while(<FH>) {
    if (/\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/) { # Search for <key> = <value>
        $key = $1; $value = $2;
        print "export $key='$value'\n";
    }
}
close(FH);
```

Now you can run the command

```
$ eval `perl exportsettings.pl`
```

from the command line, and (almost) all build settings are in the environment. (There will be some error messages, e.g. "UID: readonly variable").

If you need only your used-defined settings in the environment, you could use a unique prefix (e.g. "MY") and change the line

```
    if (/\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/) { # Search for <key> = <value>
```

to

```
    if (/\s*(MY\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/) { # Search for MY<key> = <value>
```

Comment: I hope it won't "export" the values to the system namespace, will it ?

Comment: @A-Live: It exports to the environment of the shell where the `eval` command is executed. Other shells or the system are not affected. I think that is what the OP wanted. - But I will change my answer to make that more clear, thank you for the feedback!