# How to launch lldb as a Standalone Debugger on an app running on a simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, lldb, simctl

My question is a follow-up to [How can I use Swift REPL with iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899664/how-can-i-use-swift-repl-with-ios-sdk): I'd like to be able to drop into a REPL in an iOS project and use the classes defined there.

I've already built the project and it's running on a simulator:

[image]

Now, I'd like to start a standalone LLDB debugger for the iOS project, following these commands quoted from the answer above:

```
$ xcrun lldb -- $DerivedData/$AppName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/$AppName.app
(lldb) process attach --name '$AppName' --waitfor
```

However, it is unclear to me what to substitute for `$DerivedData` and `$AppName`. The LLDB Quick Start guide, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html, didn't help me much either, as the example just provides a path without explaining how you get that path.

I've also tried following the answers at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171752/ios-simulator-installed-app-location-in-xcode-6-1, I've tried searching in the location below, but didn't find it there:

```
$ find . -name '*app'
./Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/XCTRunner.app
$ pwd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
```

How do I find the `.app` that is running on the simulator to launch `lldb` with?

### Update

As pointed out by Josh Caswell, `DerivedData` is located in my home directory, and there I can find the app which is supposedly running on the simulator:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
$ find . -name '*Venmo.app'
./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app
```

The only problem is that if I try to run the `repl` command, I get `error: Can't run the REPL without a live process.`:

```
$ lldb ./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app
(lldb) target create "./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app"
Current executable set to './VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app' (x86_64).
(lldb) repl
error: Can't run the REPL without a live process.
```

Why is the app running in the simulator not being 'picked up' as a live process?

### Update 2

Reading the instructions more carefully, it seems I have to attach to the process first:

```
(lldb) process attach --name 'Venmo' --waitfor
```

The problem now is that this command is 'hanging'. Any idea why `lldb` is not able to attach to the app's process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$DerivedData` is just the path to your project's Derived Data directory. The default for this is ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData You can see the current value in Xcode settings:

[image: Xcode settings, "Locations" tab, showing Derived Data setting]

Your project will have its own directory in there, which is the first `$AppName`. `$AppName` in `$AppName.app` is the target's Product Name from the project settings, which should just be "the name of the app" unless you've been messing with those settings.

You can also [get the values for your project using `xcodebuild`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808494): `xcodebuild -project myapp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings`

Comment: Follow-up question: do you know why I can't launch `repl` in the thus-launched standalone `lldb` (see update above)?

Comment: It looks like the app is not yet running in the simulator at that point and that you haven't attached lldb to that process.

Comment: Please stop [changing the question to include new problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).

Comment: You're right, I should limit the scope of each question. FYI, I've a separate follow-up question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757906/how-to-launch-a-swift-repl-attached-to-an-ios-app-running-on-a-simulator.