# lldb cannot find iOS app running in Simulator in order to attach

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, lldb

This is a follow-up question to [How can I use Swift REPL with iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899664/how-can-i-use-swift-repl-with-ios-sdk). I have an app named `Venmo` which is already running on a simulator:

[image]

and I can see it in the Activity Monitor:

[image]

I would like to open a Swift REPL in which can use classes defined in the `Venmo` project. Following the instructions in that answer, I first find the app in my `DerivedData` directory;

```
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
$ find . -name '*Venmo.app'
./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app
```

Then I launch a standalone LLDB following https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html. However, if I try to `process attach --name 'Venmo'`, I get an `attach failed: could not find a process named Venmo` error:

```
~/L/D/X/DerivedData> 
lldb ./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app
(lldb) target create "./VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app"
Current executable set to './VenmoWorkspace-apbzqcexodswkdfenhxlkpnlmvsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Venmo.app' (x86_64).
(lldb) process attach --name 'Venmo'
error: attach failed: could not find a process named Venmo
(lldb)
```

I don't understand why LLDB can't find this process, even though I see it in my Activity Monitor?

Comment: How did you run Venmo.app in the Simulator?  By default Xcode runs simulator apps under the debugger, and on Darwin only one debugger can be attached to a process at a time.  lldb's `process attach` ignores already debugged processes, which would explain why it said it couldn't find it.  You can tell whether a process is being debugged by running `ps` and looking at the STAT column.  If that has an `X`, then the process is being debugged.