# Running code on iOS device instead of simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Every time I try running app on an iPhone I receive:

"Xcode cannot run using the selected device. 
No provisioned devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS devise with a recent enough version of iOS to run your aplication or use iOS simulator"

I'm enrolled in iOS Developer University Program which in theory let's me to test own code at my iPhone.
I have provision certificates installed on my Mac and iPhone as well. Have iPhone added as device for development.

I have iOS 8.3 on my phone and Xcode 6.3 on a Mac installed.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is your device added to the provisioning profile too?

Comment: Yes, it is. Checked udid twice. Everything's correct.

Comment: did u added proper udid? Get the device udid from iTunes. Not from any app.

Comment: @DurgaSriram did it as you've said.

Comment: Check the deployment target of your app. In the Project Navigator (top left) there will be a blue folded paper looking thingie. Under the General tab for the Target, it'll have a Deployment Target and Devices (iPhone, iPad, Universal).
This post may be helpful, too.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html

Comment: @AdrianB already checked that, set it to 8.3 and "iPhone"

Comment: Have you gone through this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999167/ios-8-how-to-use-device-for-development

Comment: @AdrianB it's a different issue.

Comment: I made it work by just running the code again, then quit Xcode, run it again and it doesn't work again.

Comment: If you haven't rebooted, I'd give that a whirl. If you've already rebooted, you might consider going medieval and nuking derived data and then rebooting. (I'm assuming you've already cleaned caches w/in Xcode). If it works inconsistently, it sounds like there's something flakey going on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761934/xcode-derived-data-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your phone operating system match with Xcode operating system? For example, if your phone has 7.0 and you are deploying the build from 8.3, then of your course, your phone will not match and cannot be detected and will give you that error.

In other words, Check **Deployment Target**, it should match with your phone operating system, otherwise your device is not recognized.

How to check:
**General-->Deployment Info--> Deployment Target**

Comment: Yes it does, checked this settings on the very beginning.